# Using an inductor as a LF antenna

Tags: rf, inductor, inductance

I would like to miniaturize an existing antenna I built, which is just a typical ferrite rod antenna.

When makes a ferrite antenna different from an inductor ? Can I just use a same value inductor as a replacement for my antenna ? Provided SRF and DC resistance are good enough for my use cas.

Doesn't the size of the magnetic field depent entierely on the inductance of the coil, regardless of shape or size ?

EDIT : LF antenna, not VLF

An image to illustrate what I mean :
[image]

Comment: Size, shape matters. A l-o-n-g ferrite rod makes a better VLF antenna.

Comment: I understand a L/D ratio of 20 is optimal, but this is done to increase effective permeability, effectively increasing the inductance and thereby the Q factor. I still don't understand how this makes it different from a normal inductor ?

Comment: Is this a TUNED, resonant high-Q ferrite VLF antenna?   Or just a pure inductor?  (E.g., all AM broadcast-band antennas have a tuning cap across the ferrite loopstick.  Makes a gigantic improvement in microwatts via an "EA" effect (Effective Area of wave-absorption.)  Also, doubling ferrite length will more than double incoming microwatts.  (Also, op-amp negative-resistor circuit is the VLF equiv of Superregen technique, giving infinite Q.  VLF people don't use this simple trick, only HF and VHF?)

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the title to LF, bit tired right now... It is for a tuned circuit, to be used in near-field reception.

Answer (score 2):

> What makes a ferrite antenna different from an inductor ?

Antennas work by electrically coupling to free space, to either radiate or receive energy -- it's their whole purpose.  An ideal inductor radiates no energy -- that would defeat the purpose of an antenna.

> Can I just use a same value inductor as a replacement for my antenna ? Provided SRF and DC resistance are good enough for my use case.

No.  In general you'll get an inductor closer to the ideal inductor than a purpose-built antenna (even one on a ferrite rod).  In the worst case, you'll get an inductor that's shielded or has a toroidal core and has very little leakage.

> Doesn't the size of the magnetic field depend entirely on the inductance of the coil, regardless of shape or size ?

No.  The size (and more importantly the degree to which it leaks to free space) depends on the construction of the inductor.

In general, up to at least a wavelength or so, the bigger an antenna is with respect to the wavelength of the RF you're generating, the better it couples to free space.  This means that it wastes less energy on heating itself up, and radiates more to the outside world (or does a better job of picking up external signals).

For VLF antennas, unless you're doing something heroic and possibly in violation of local airspace rules, bigger is always better.

The reason that VLF antennas are built onto ferrite rods is because they need to fit into some human-scale space -- but when you do that, you end up giving up a lot in performance.

Comment: Edited to LF antenna. The antennas come from a Silabs application note, I understand bigger is better for antennas, but wouldn't the inductor on the left behave just like the tiny antenna on the right ? To someone who doesn't know, they would probably say these are inductors, not antennas.

Comment: First, you don't give dimensions for the inductors on the left, and second, the construction of the core they're wound on (with the "caps") will tend to self-shield slightly, reducing the radiated field for the same outer dimensions.

Comment: From what I understand there is still part of the magnetic field that will leak, so assuming it has similar dimensions and inductance, it would make a slightly poorer antenna ?

Comment: INDUCTANCE IS IRRELEVANT, since will be perfectly canceled by the parallel variable capacitor.  Q-factor is everything, Effective Area is everything.  Q-factor is impacted by wire resistance, and iirc, EA is proportional to ferrite length squared.  Smaller ferrite is a bad idea.  Thinner wire is a bad idea

Comment: I wouldn't say inductance is irrelevant, a 1nH inductor with a big capacitor probably won't make for a good antenna as far as I understand. As for AE, I understand the bigger the better, this doesn't stop manufacturers from making very small ferrite antennas, its a tradeoff I'm ok with. For Q factor, if I find an inductor with an acceptable Q for my application, isn't this sufficient then ?

Comment: Also, at LF frequencies, skin depth really isn't an issue, so factoring only DC resistance, most inductors I've seen provide really high Q.

Comment: @Ryan it isn't clear to me if you're trying to understand what you've been told, or if you just want your preconceptions validated.  In either case -- go find an antenna book.  Both the ARRL and GSRB publish materials on antennas that are accessible to ordinary people.  They explain all of this in much greater length than can fit into a StackExchange posting.  All your questions will be answered -- you just need to take the effort to study up.